# how to get jupyter notebook color theme into vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

how to get  Jupyter notebook colour theme into vs code I dont want to open jupyter notebook in vs code I know that but I wanted to know how can I get similar colour theme in vs code which is there in jupyter notebook. I checked into vs code market place to see if there is any extension which can make vs code colour theme like jupyter notebook but there wasn't any.

Answer (score 6):

Added in v1.69 for notebook backgrounds:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "notebook.editorBackground": "#60759b"
}
```

Some new color options for notebook cells were just added to v1.47.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_47.md#notebooks

> all within the `workbench.colorCustomizations` object as above example

`notebook.cellBorderColor`: The border color for notebook cells

`notebook.cellHoverBackground`: The background color of a cell when the cell is hovered

`notebook.cellInsertionIndicator`: The color of the notebook cell insertion indicator

`notebook.focusedCellBackground`: The background color of a cell when the cell is focused

`notebook.focusedCellBorder`: The color of the cell's top and bottom border when the cell is focused

`notebook.focusedCellShadow`: The color of the cell shadow when cells are focused

`notebook.focusedEditorBorder`: The color of the notebook cell editor border

---

`notebook.cellEditorBackground` : added in vscode v1.59

Comment: I don't think this is for Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Precision : This should be in "workbench.colorCustomizations" in settings.json. Don't forget to add quotes.

Comment: Has anybody a valid `workbench.colorCustomizations`configuration which is equal to the default jupyter theme?