# Can I change the look of pandas data frame in vscode jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I saw people working with Jupyter notebook have quite nice view of the data frame. But my Jupyter notebook in VScode show the same thing as in the terminal. How do I change this? Would change the theme help?

Thank you.

Edit: thanks for your reply. Here is what I want:
[image: pic 1]

Here is what it look like now:
[image: pic 2]

I'm OK with any theme, as long as the data look clearer with row separation or at least header separation.

Comment: `"quite nice view of the data frame"` <- like what? are there screenshots somewhere?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758505/836330 and colorCustomizations.

Comment: Do you have an example of what kind of theme you want?

Comment: @tdy. I've just added the screenshots.

Comment: @DerekO. I've added some screenshots. I don't mind the theme as long as the table look clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Panda's [to_markdown](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) function, which requires the [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) library installed in python, provides various plain text formatting for tables which show on VS Code Jupyter editor, such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"animal_1": ["elk", "pig"], "animal_2": ["dog", "quetzal"]})
print(df.to_markdown())

|    | animal_1   | animal_2   |
|---:|:-----------|:-----------|
|  0 | elk        | dog        |
|  1 | pig        | quetzal    |
```

Answer (score 0):

I reached the same case and tried setting up the Notebook extension to default. It worked for my case. You can see the detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74806610/19371934)!