# How to change pandas dataframe style to default?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, styles

I want to change the dataframe style from image 1 to the style in image 2. I tried to use `pd.reset_option('all')` and `pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False`)` , but it was not converted to my expected style. So, I need some advice for my case.

Current dataframe style

[image]

Expected dataframe style

[image]

That's my code:

[image]

Many thanks for your support!

Comment: This is just how it's displayed. In the top you are printing the dataframe (e.g., `print(df)`), whereas in the second it is how Jupyter Notebook often renders it if you just type the var name of the dataframe (e.g., `df`).

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code above. I don't know how to setup to default as my expected table. Tks for your attention!

Comment: Are you using standard Jupyter Notebook in browser? Some specific IDE?  Could be an IDE setting hence why I ask

Comment: I used Jupyter Notebook in VS Code, Pandas version is 1.5.2, Python version is 3.10.6

Comment: Maybe a VSCode issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68109114/868044

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52225216/868044

Comment: Tks for your advice, but I tried to reset all setting Jupyter Notebook extension and Vs Code to default but that was not resolved for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this case. My solution is below:

Step 1: Open VS code setting space and find Notebook with tag '@tag:notebookLayout'

Step 2: Remove items in **Cell Toolbar Location**, keep only default as the image below.

[image]

Step 3: Find the "Notebook: Editor Options Customizations" section and cick on Edit in settings.json

[image]

Step 4: Replace all current settings code with this code, and add your python.exe file path to "python.defaultInterpreterPath".

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": ".\\path\\to\\python\\.exe",
    "jupyter.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "jupyter.widgetScriptSources": [
        "jsdelivr.com",
        "unpkg.com"
    ],
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastColorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "workbench.preferredHighContrastLightColorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "workbench.preferredLightColorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "outline.problems.colors": false,
    "notebook.editorOptionsCustomizations": {
        

    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    }
}
```