# How can I overwrite default background color for outputs in VSCode's Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, themes

When printing output of cell in VSCode (e.g. containing geometry object, see below) Notebook is ignoring current theme and giving me white background color.
Is there any possibility to change this to color of my choice?

In JupyterLab there is no such problem, as background is compatible with set theme.

[image]

I can change Matplotlib output color but no luck with other type of outputs.

Comment: Does the `notebook.editorBackground` `colorCustomization` help?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62758505/836330

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('dark_background'')
```

See [customizing matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) for more info.